# How to ensure security for my webserver which is exposed to internet via a loadbalancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Let's say I have a web server that i am planning to put under a loadbalancer(should keep this in public or private subnet?), so to do this how can I make sure the security to my webserver. How can I deny any hacking attempt to my webserver, because it will be open to public. How can i ensure the security for my webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Load Balancer is accessed by users from the Internet, so it should go in a **public subnet**.

The Amazon EC2 instance running your web server should *not* be accessible from the Internet, so it should go into a **private subnet**.

If you are using an **Application Load Balancer**, the security groups should be:

- A security group on the Load Balancer (`LB-SG`) that permits access on ports 80 and 443 from `0.0.0.0/0`
- A security group on the Amazon EC2 instance(s) (`App-SG`) that permit inbound access on port 443 (or other) from `LB-SG`. That is, `App-SG` specifically reference `LB-SG` as the source for traffic.

If you are using a **Network Load Balancer**, note that the load balancer itself does not accept a security group. Therefore, use:

- A security group on the Amazon EC2 instance(s) that permits access on ports 80 and 443 from `0.0.0.0/0`
- This group will be used to determine what traffic will be permitted to go from the Internet, through the Load Balancer, and to the EC2 instance(s)